# Large string input in C

Tags: c, string, file, input

I am trying to take input from the console and print it into the text file. Input can be really large (20 000 digits)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100000

int main()
{ 
  char id[MAX];
  FILE *fp = fopen("new.txt", "w");

  fgets(id, MAX, stdin); 

  for(int i=0;i<strlen(id);i++){
    fprintf(fp, "%c", id[i]);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

My code prints to file only first 4096 characters. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Why are you printing one character at a time rather than the entire string in one go?

Comment: Maybe there's a newline character somewhere in the input? `fgets()` will stop there.

Comment: Read about environmental limits in the C standard

Comment: Why are you reading more than one character at a time?  That just complicates things.  Read one char, write it, repeat.

Comment: And why are you typing 20000 digits!?!  I assume you actually mean that you are reading from stdin rather than from a console; do not conflate them.

Comment: The 4096-char limit might be with your console, not your program.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @GovindParmar: Which of those limits would apply here?  I see a limit of 4095 bytes in a source line, or in a string literal, but neither of those applies here.  Anyway, I wouldn't expect any modern implementation to actually have such a limit.

Comment: @NateEldredge The minimum of 4095 chars also applies to format-string conversions in printf-family functions. Though if it's a loop printing one character at a time and reaching that limit, that still doesn't explain OP's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For reading and writing large amounts of data (rather than shorter lines of text), consider using [`fread()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [`fwrite()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) rather than [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`fprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: I can't think of any situation where this would make a difference.

Comment: @NateEldredge: `fgets()` stops at newline? fprintf of characters is one function call, possibly including format string parsing, per char printed out? Better conveying intent?

Comment: Okay.  But assuming OP is correct that the input does not contain a newline, this will not solve their problem.

Comment: @NateEldredge: OP doesn't say that in the question. But fair enough.